# why my IgnoreRoute does not work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to prevent users access for my "~/Content/..." folder I wrote it as follow in "Global.asax.cs"  and put this line of code at the top of every other routes
`routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");`
but it does not work. in fact user can see every files in content folder by type the URL in browser. 
am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How did you figure out that it does not work? Give example.

You may have put it last in the Routing table. So try to move it up so that it gets added to the routing table **first**. The route collection is an ordered list of routes.

Also try this : `Routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/");`, but your version of ignore is also correct and it should work.

Lastly, I do not know what you mean when you say the user can see all the contents of the Content folder : Isn't that the point? User must be able to download files from the folder, and we usually just need MVC to ignore the requests from coming into the framework, and so that IIS can directly serve those files.

or did you mean Directory browsing is enabled, and you want to disable that : In that case go to IIS manager, and select your website and look for the Directory browsing option and disable it as shown [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: i put that on the top of every other routes (does not work) and write your suggested Routes (does not work again). by "does not work" i mean when use enter something like : `/Content/Site.css` in the browser my css file will be shown in the browser and i want to ignore this behavior

Comment: @Rzassar if you want a browser to load the css and use it to render your page, you can't prevent users from also showing the css in the browser, it's simply not possible...

Comment: @Rzassar: Entering `/Content/Site.css` in the address bar and seeing the stylesheet is normal. It happens on **every** site on the internet, simply go to any site and use firebug, find out the link to its stylesheet and enter it in the adderssbar and see.

Comment: @Zasz thank you! you give me two light: "No problem i can see your sites css files and you can see mine! that is normal" in the other hand : "if you wanna use a css file in your pages, you have to put it visible by your web page and Perforcely by user"

Answer (score 2):

Your problem cannot be solved by routing constraints. There are 3 significant steps in processing request:

1. IIS got request.
2. IIS watch at filesystem and search for direct correspondence to file
3. If IIS didn't found any file - it gives request to ASP.NET MVC for processing.

So, you need to configure folder security to forbidden direct access to files, but allow access to application, as [here](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/hiddenSegments). 
But I don't recommend to secure folder, that should be shared. I don't believe that your site shouldn't have images to display :) If you have some secured content, you need to create another folder.

Comment: do you mean i cannot ignore access from my.css file and other images just by writing some `Routes.Ignore()`?

Comment: I mean you should separate files that you don't want user have ability to download and files that user MUST have ability to download. You can't forbidden unauthorized user to download images "by url" and return to user pages with "images" simultaneously, because this pictures browser request "by url" too.

Comment: okay! but what about my css file? it`s located in ~/Content/Site.css and i want to prevent this file to be seen by the user. is there a solution as simple as using IgnoreRoute() other that 'configuring folder security'?

Comment: okay! i got it. thank you very much. sorry about that stupid question it`s all because i`m new to web developing.